# How do I fix a facebook fanpage that loads with a blank white screen?

Tags: facebook, migration

I has a facebook business page for my company and wanted a fanpage.
I used the migration tool and now when I go to the page when I logged in
it is a blank white screen and when I do it from the web (not signed in)
it displays the same.  I would greatly appreciate anyone who is able to tell
me how to fix this issue.

Here is the link to my fanpage:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/getting_started?page_id=351121568256868

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug update that conflicts with the language of the user. Change the interface language of your accounts in your setting.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted does not look like the right url..

Maybe you mean this page:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Pancakes-Alpharetta/351121568256868

or it's simpler form:
http://www.facebook.com/351121568256868

---

## Edit

As I wrote in the comments, this question is not a programming question, and this site is not the best place for it (which is why I see that someone already voted to close it).

Also, I have no personal experience with this subject, so this info is from a few searches I made, my apologies if some are not  relevant.

Have you checked these:
 - [Converting Your Personal Account to a Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/help?page=213602951994043)
 - [Reversing the Facebook Profile to Page Migration](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150187904821603)

Also, there are some bug reports:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&&search_statuses[0]=open&search_texts[0]=page%20migration

And you might want to consider reporting another bug if none of those matches your problem.

Other than this, I have no idea how to help.

Comment: Yes neither of those links work.  How do I fix it please? and yes I do mean those.

Comment: Well, I don't know, and I'm sorry to say that this site is not the place for this, since it's only for programming questions. You might want to start here: http://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=fan+page+migration, and if that does not help try to contact facebook.

Comment: I apologize I thought this was a program issue.  What if I create a new page will the likes from my current page be able to carried over?  Sorry if you do not know that I just do not know where else to look I contacted facebook but its been a month now.

Comment: Check out my modified answer.